# JS How to import file from importer folder, not owner folder

Tags: javascript, import

For example I have next file structure

```
src
| - lib
|   | - customImport.js
| - app
|   | - app.js
|   | - style.scss
```

`customImport.js` - contains one function which imports specified filepath

```
const customImport = (filepath) => {
   require(filename);
};
```

`app.js` - uses this function

```
import { customImport } from '../lib/customImport';
customImport('./style.scss')
```

The issue is that `require(filename)` executes from `./src/lib` folder, not from expecting folder `./src/app`.

> Module not found: Can't resolve './style.scss' in '.../src/lib'

How to write correct code where `require(filename)` will be called from `./src/app/app.js` file?

Comment: I wonder if you can use `__dirname`?

Comment: when I pass `__dirname` as parameter, passed parameter equals to `/`, so we heve next error: `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Cannot find module '//style.scss'`